# chef - making yum localinstall of cookbook_file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, yum

I have some certain rpm's that need to be moved to a box, and yum localinstall'ed there.

Now I know how to make `notifies` for upon file creation yum would install something from repo, but I don't know how to specify source in this case.

So for now, I have the following:

```
cookbook_file "mksh-39-5.el6.x86_64.rpm" do
        path "/tmp/mksh-39-5.el6.x86_64.rpm"
        action :create
end

package "mksh-39-5.el6.x86_64.rpm" do
        source "/tmp/mksh-39-5.el6.x86_64.rpm"
        action :install
end
```

The question is - how do I bind them, so that installation would be called upon file creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer is "use notifications" but as you talk about many files I would loop over a list like this:

```
['mksh-39-5.el6.x86_64.rpm','package2.rpm'].each do |p| # start from an array of packages, could be an attributes like node['my_namespace']['packages']
  package p do # no need to do interpolation here, we just need the name
    source "/tmp/#{p}" # Here we have to concatenate path and name
    action :nothing # do nothing, just define the resource
  end

  cookbook_file "/tmp/#{p}" do # I prefer setting the destination in the name
    source p                   # and tell the source name, so in case of different platfom I can take advantage of the resolution of files withint the cookbook tree
    action :create 
    notifies :install, "package[/tmp/#{p}]", :immediately 
  end
end
```

The `:immediately` is to fire the package install as soon as the file has been placed, if there's dependencies, you'll have to manage the order of the packages in the array